# Deal with Index in DataGridView in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, indexing, datagridview

My `DataGridView` has only two rows. I have set `AllowUserToAddNewRow = False`. I am filling rows in `DataGridView` from database. I want to transfer its value in a textbox on `KeyDown` event by pressing Enter Key. When I press Enter key in the `DataGridView` to select the contents of first row, the `DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index` returns 1. In the same way when I select the second row and press Enter key then same happens here, means it also returns `DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index` as 1. Is there any concept so that I can deal with this problem?

What I have tried:

```
RowIndx = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
```

Answer (score 1):

You con do it simply like this :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim RowIndx As Integer
        RowIndx = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).RowIndex
        MsgBox(RowIndx)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Hope it helped :)**